# Javascript is not loading after the page is scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I added a script to trigger the enter event, it works fine until we scroll the page. when we scroll, dynamically it adds another page(It is ajax call), But from the second-page script is not loading.

This is the code:

```
<%= form_tag add_comments_statuses_path, :data => {:toggle => "validator"}, :html => {:class=>"form-horizontal row-fluid shift_from", :id => "comments_form_#{status}"}, method: :post, :remote => true  do %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <a href="#" class="cmt-thumb">
        <%= image_tag current_user.profile_pic, :style=>"width:40px!important; height:40px;" %>
    </a>
    <div class="controls cmt-form " style="margin-bottom:10px;">
      <%= text_area_tag  'comment', " ", :class => "form-control", :id => "comment-form-#{status}", :placeholder =>"Write a comment...",:data => {:error => "Please Enter Comment"}, required: true %>
      <span class="help-block with-errors" id = "error-#{status}"></span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" value="<%= status %>" name="status_id">
<% end %>


<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#comment-form-<%= status %>").keypress(function(event) {
       if (event.which == 13) {
          event.preventDefault();
          if ($(this).val() != " ")
           $(this).closest('form').submit();
       }
    });
  })
</script>
```

Comment: you said its ajax call i guess that the reason, since the ajax call is async that means the ajax result will be shown when its not even complete means he DOM is not 'live'  try    $("#comment-form-<%= status %>").delegate('keypress' function (event) { your code;});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working after scroll and in second page because new page **not able to recognize keypress event** because new added html is not exist in initial DOM.

To resolve this issue you have to write **keypress event inline** and call function from there as below:

```
<input type='text' onkeypress = "return yourFunction(event)"/>
```

**Note:** Please check the onkeypress event call syntax once

Comment: Thanks, I changed the complete code. Now it's working fine.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to upvote but it some error message